# C++ Linking Issue

Tags: c++, linux, g++, dynamic-linking

Let's say I have a shared library called libfoo.so that also depends on another shared library called libbar.so. In libfoo.so, the only capability it provides is a class that stores two integers and can return the value of those two integers added together.

libfoo.so:

```
// Foo.hpp

class Foo
{
  int x, y;
public:
  Foo(int x, int y);
  int add() const;
};
```

Now, in libbar.so, there are two classes: a Bar1 class that simply stores a string and a Bar2 class that stores an integer that is calculated by creating a Foo object and using the add() function to generate a new integer.

```
// Bar1.hpp

class Bar1
{
  std::string str;
public:
  Bar1(const std::string& str);
  const std::string& getString() const;
};


// Bar2.hpp

#include "foo.hpp"

class Bar2
{
  int z;
public:
  Bar2(int x, int y);
  int getInt() const;
};
```

Now, I want to write a program that uses Bar1. I do not care about Bar2. My very simple program looks like this:

```
// Test.cpp

#include <iostream>

#include "Bar1.hpp"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  Bar1 bar1("Hello");
  cout << bar1.getString() << endl;
}
```

I compile this program like so:

```
g++ -c test.cpp -o test.o
g++ -o test test.o -lbar
```

The error that is generated is:

```
undefined reference to 'Foo::Foo(int, int)' 
undefined reference to 'Foo::add() const'
```

This can be fixed by specifying '-lfoo' to the linker. However, I am now linking in a library that my binary will never use.

Is there a way to clean this up where the compiler understands that my binary does not care about resolving these symbols since I never use Bar2 anywhere in my program?

EDIT:

Adding the implementations of the classes. I didn't think that it mattered. Here they are:

```
// Foo.cpp

#include "Foo.hpp"

Foo::Foo(int new_x, int new_y)
{
  x = new_x;
  y = new_y;
}

int Foo::add() const
{
  return x + y;
}
```

And here is Bar1.cpp:

```
// Bar1.cpp

#include "Bar1.hpp"

Bar1::Bar1(const std::string& the_str)
{
  str = the_str;
}

const std::string& Bar1::getString() const
{
  return str;
}
```

And here is Bar2.cpp:

```
// Bar2.cpp

#include "Bar2.hpp"

Bar2::Bar2(int x, int y)
{
  Foo foo(x, y);
  z = foo.add();
}

int Bar2::getInt() const
{
  return z;
}
```

Note that it should be obvious that I am writing these classes like this purely for experimentation purposes. I am playing around with the linker and how a developer would link to libraries and use them.

Comment: Briefly, no. But, when you linked `libbar.so`, it could have been provided the `-lfoo` on the link line. Then, the linker would have pulled in `libfoo.so` for you when you only put `-lbar`.

Comment: Not with direct linkage, like that. Use `dlopen()` with the `RTLD_LAZY` flag, and `dlsym()`. This won't directly work with `C++` code, it will be necessary to trampoline your way via `C`-linkage functions, which is why I'm not giving this as an offishul answer. But it is theoretically doable.

Comment: Something's calling those `Foo` functions somewhere

Comment: Yes, but that "something" will not get executed, so with lazy-loading you can get away with it.

Comment: you didn't provide implementation for classes foo and bar, include string in bar1.hpp

Comment: @jxh I believe this is what I want. I want my end user to not have to specify all of the other libraries.

Answer (score 0):

where is foo.cpp and bar.cpp? you didn't implement classes foo and bar:

```
// foo.cpp
#include "Foo.hpp"

Foo::Foo(int X, int Y) : x(X), y(Y){}
int Foo::add()const{return x + y;}


// Bar1.cpp

#include "bar1.hpp"

Bar1::Bar1(const std::string& STR) : str(STR){}
const std::string& Bar1::getString() const{return str;}


// Bar2.cpp

#include "foo.hpp"

Bar2::Bar2(int X, int Y) : x(X), y(Y) {z = x + y;}  
int Bar2::getInt() const{ return z;}
```